# Where to ask off-topic questions?

Tags: discussion, scope

There are some good answers about 'best programming books', 'best XX language tutorials', etc. Can we have have a Stack Exchange site to cover such off-topic questions?

For example:

- [Language Books/Tutorials for popular languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873/language-books-tutorials-for-popular-languages)
- [What is the single most influential book every programmer should read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read)

Where should a question like this go?

Comment: No to my knowledge. Even programmers.stackexchange.com close them as off-topic. Amazon reviews are relatively good though.

Comment: It is off-topic where to ask off-topic questions  ;)

Comment: It is off-topic to discuss what's the influential video/talks for programmers on Amazon reviews :), I thought programmers.stackexchange.com is a place to ask such a question.

Comment: @Gohan [Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl) / http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Comment: @gnat I just read your comment after asked a `off-topic` question on Programmers.SE, will discover a better place for "toilet bowl"

Comment: @Gohan we (P.SE) actually copied the close reason for 'resource request' from Stack Overflow (see [What should our predefined off-topic reasons be?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6025/40980))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) is the only place where you can ask such questions.

See also: [Where to or how to ask "Best of" Questions for what software tools to use](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194974/where-to-or-how-to-ask-best-of-questions-for-what-software-tools-to-use)

Comment: Let me discover the chat place, :)